# how to purge cache in hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using hystrix in my app server in springboot. Request caching is done automatically by hystrixCommand. I need to purge my cache after certain interval in hystrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling

```java
HystrixRequestCache.clear(cacheKey)
```

For this to work you need to implement `getCacheKey()`.

Request caching is enabled by implementing the `getCacheKey()` method on a HystrixCommand object:

```java
@Override
protected String getCacheKey() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}
```

Comment: How to do it after a certain interval of time

Comment: You can write a scheduler for that

Comment: Also the cache is only available till the request context. In that case it is possible to retain the cache for a longer period?